# Error when feeding the name of a counter from one macro into another

Tags: counters, expansion

As part of trying to get to grips with the technical side of TeX/LetTeX, I have been trying to write my own class files. In writing one such file, I found the need to have a macro that takes two counters and returns the counter which has the largest value.

For this task, I believe, I have cooked up a suitable macro in `\getmaxoftwocounters`, defined below, which seems to work fine in my testing. However, when I try to feed the result of this macro into other macros (in particular when I want to get a formatted representation of the counter to use for typesetting) I get an error.

There is a minimal example of my problem below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\getmaxoftwocounters}[2]
{\ifnum\value{#1}<\value{#2}{#2}\else{#1}\fi}


\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounterA}
\newcounter{mycounterB}
\setcounter{mycounterA}{1}
\setcounter{mycounterB}{2}
\null
\getmaxoftwocounters{mycounterA}{mycounterB}
\null\\
\arabic{mycounterB}
%\arabic{\getmaxoftwocounters{mycounterA}{mycounterB}}

\end{document}
```

When I uncomment the commented line I get the error `! Missing number, treated as zero.`. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? The only thing I can think of is a problem in the order of macro expansion, but I have tried peppering in `\expandafter` and `\edef` at various places to no avail, and am now as such at a loss of what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the braces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\getmaxoftwocounters}[2]{%
  \ifnum\value{#1}<\value{#2}%
    #2%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}


\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounterA}
\newcounter{mycounterB}
\setcounter{mycounterA}{1}
\setcounter{mycounterB}{2}

\getmaxoftwocounters{mycounterA}{mycounterB}

\arabic{mycounterB}

\arabic{\getmaxoftwocounters{mycounterA}{mycounterB}}

\end{document}
```

With your code, you'd get

```
\arabic{{mycounterB}}
```

that's syntax error.

The code could be written as

```
\newcommand{\getmaxoftwocounters}[2]
  {\ifnum\value{#1}<\value{#2}#2\else#1\fi}
```

but you'd lose in readability.

<sup>Please, don't use the `minimal` class. It's not meant for examples of this kind.</sup>

Comment: Wow, didn't think that would have been the cause. Many thanks!